# two consecutive newline characters as a delimiter - C/C++

Tags: c++, getline

I'm writing a getline function below but I want the delimiting character to be two consecutive newline characters such the function stops reading once it reaches a *blank* line.

```
in.getline(temp, 127, delimiter);
```

Is it possible to do this with getline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiter must be a single character for `istream::getline`. However, you could always buffer the result yourself, checking the next character (`peek`) to see if its a newline.

Answer (score 3):

No, but a <strike>simple</strike>(not quite as simple as I thought at first) loop will do it.

```
std::string s, temp;
while (std::getline(in, temp, delimiter) && !temp.empty())
    s += temp, s += delimiter;
if (!s.empty())
    s.resize(s.size() - 1) // or s.pop_back() if C++11
```

Comment: Don;y you want ot add the new line character to s? `s += temp + '\n';`